# Why does the return value of a function print even though no explicit printing method is called (ex. document.write)?

Tags: javascript

I just started javascript a few days ago and was playing around with different ways to print the return value of a function.

```
<script>
function produceMessage(){
    var msg= 'This should print';
    return msg;
}

</script>

<span id="mySpan"></span>
```

Both these lines of code call methods like write or createTextNode to print the message.

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(produceMessage()));
document.write(produceMessage());
```

However this line does not call a such a method but the return value is still printing.

```
document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML=produceMessage();
```

My intuition tells me that in order to have the return value appear on the screen, you need to call some sort of method that would allow it to be printed, like in this example:

```
document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML=document.write(produceMessage());
```

However this is incorrect and results in undefined output.

Comment: PS: Do not ever use document.write after the load of the page since it will wipe the page and all scripts on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `innerHTML` of a element to a string results in the HTML of that element being changed to that string. So,

```
document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML=produceMessage();
```

- Calls `produceMessage()`
- Sets the innerHTML of element with id `mySpan` to result

Your function `produceMessage` returns a string, so the innerHTML of that element is set to `This should print`.

Your next statement,

```
document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML=document.write(produceMessage());
```

- Calls `produceMessage()`
- Calls `document.write()` with the result, which appends `This should print` to the document
- Sets the innerHTML of element with id `mySpan` to the return value of `document.write`

`document.write` returns `undefined`, so the innerHTML of that element is set to the string representation of `undefined`.